# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone I try to update to boolean in my table, so I had Error PDOException and I don't Why :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax
```

My line code sql is this :

```
public function updateSignal(Comments $comment)
{
    $req = 'UPDATE Comments SET signal = TRUE WHERE idComments = :comment';
    $result = $this->getBdd()->prepare($req);
    $result->bindValue(':comment', $comment->getIdComments());

    return $result->execute();
}
```

I don't find where is my error syntax, Please need help Thanks

Comment: Do NOT shorten the error message.

Comment: What is the return type of `$comment->getIdComments()` the "s" on comments makes it sound like a plural so it could return an array.

Also can you confirm that `$this->getBdd()` is using the PDO class and not a library?

Comment: Try change true to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIGNAL` is a reserved word. It's best to avoid it, but you can use it if you wrap it in backticks.

```
$req = 'UPDATE Comments SET `signal` = TRUE WHERE idComments = :comment';
```

[(MySQL reserved words)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

Comment: @AlprodGrm You're most welcome. Please remember to accept an answer by clicking the check mark